# Accessing kubeflow pipelines from GKE Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow-pipelines

I have installed `Kubeflow` on a `private GKE Cluster`  from the GCP Console using below service
AI Platform --> Pipelines
The `kubeflow pipeline` UI can be accessed fine.

But my confusion how can I access the UI from internet as there are no `ingress/LBs` created for this workload  as only services of type `Cluster IP` are created as a part of kubeflow installation

[image]

The `Kubeflow Pipeline` URL is as follows which resolves to a Public IP Address.

```
 https://xxxxxxxxxxx-dot-us-xxxxxx.pipelines.googleusercontent.com
```

I don't see any entry in CloudDNS but seems like the URL is exposed similar to how `CloudRun/App Engine` URLs are exposed.

Under `Application` TAB from `GKE Console` , following can be seen

[image]

Please ignore the error with respect to "Status" from above image as I changed the number of Nodes to 0.

Comment: in short, you want to understand how is possible that your can access to `https://xxxxxxxxxxx-dot-us-xxxxxx.pipelines.googleusercontent.com` when you don't have any load balancer nor ingress on your GKE cluster ?

Comment: Yes..Correct..Thanks

Comment: According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/setting-up-an-mlops-environment#using_a_standalone_deployment_of_kubeflow_pipelines), the web-based UI and REST APIs for Kubeflow Pipelines are exposed through a public URL using an [inverting proxy and agent](https://github.com/google/inverting-proxy). You should be able to see a proxy agent in your cluster workloads.